# How can I trigger a function when certain text on a specific element appears?

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey

I need to add some code to a webpage when a certain text appears on it.

So I load a webpage, and this appears:

```
<div id="someid" class="someclass" style=""></div>
```

I don't want anything to happen. But at some point this appears:

```
<div id="someid" class="someclass" style="">Some text here...</div>
```

When the text appears, I want Greasemonkey to add this somewhere on the page.

```
<div id="idbla">This is text...</div>
```

I don't care where this is added. It doesn't need to be appended to anything. It doesn't even need to be visible on the page. I just want it to appear somewhere in the HTML of the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to detect text changes to your element:

```js
function main() {
  console.log('Text added!');
}

const wantedDiv = document.querySelector('#someid');
const button = document.querySelector('#add-text');
button.addEventListener('click', () => wantedDiv.innerText = 'text...');

const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
  if (wantedDiv.innerText) main();
  observer.disconnect();
});
const config = {
  characterData: false,
  attributes: false,
  childList: true,
  subtree: false
};

observer.observe(wantedDiv, config);
```

```html
<div id="someid" class="someclass" style=""></div>

<button id="add-text">Add text</button>
```